# Importing .bacpac fails on 'Importing Database'

Tags: sql-server-express, bacpac

I am trying to import a `.bacpac` file into my SQL Server 2016 Express database, however it's failing on the [Importing Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msOFF.png) step. Has anyone seen this before? Are there any common causes for it to fail at this step?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've run into this problem, it's been because the `.bacpac` came from a different version of SQL Server than I was running. Last time it was because the backup came from SQL Server 2016 and I was running 2014. Upgraded to 2016 and the backup imported just fine.

Comment: I had the same experience except I had 2016 SP1 and the .bacpac came from 2017. I had to upgrade to 2017 and then it worked.

Comment: Where can I find this new version?